# Prevent Intercom auto opening upon new messages

Tags: javascript, web, chat

Intercom messenger opens automatically upon the arrival of new messages. Can we disable this with a configuration? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRhTZ.png)

My biggest concern is when the automatic popup opens with the arrival of a new message, the unread message count is rest to 0 automatically. Can we override this default behaviour?

Comment: You should ask intercom support ...